# Migration from SQL Server2008r2 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration, mysql-workbench

we are converting MSSQL to MySQL using exp/imp wizard in MSSQL server 2008R2.

I have followed this link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/826cd1e8-cce3-4c08-839d-f6931ac75ef5

1. I have downloaded MySQL Connector/ODBC 3.51 and created DSN named "TestTAP"
2. And then i have used SQLServer --> TestDB --> Tasks --> Export Data, i have got Imp and Exp wizard

Please visit this link.....

http://www.flickr.com/photos/83606059@N04/show/

My ODBC driver is not appearing in the IMP and Exp wizard destination list

where am doing wrong?

Please help me folks

Regards

Comment: Why don't you download the latest MySQL driver? 3.51 is an old one! http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL just added a migration tool to migrate into their Workbench tool. Details can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration.html). I fail to see how it's going to migrate anything more than the most noddy database, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

The new Migration Wizard that comes with [MySQl Workbench 5.2.41](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) will help you to migrate both the tables and their data. You can have an overview of its capabilities here:

[How-To: Guide to Database Migration from Microsoft SQL Server using MySQL Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/?p=1350)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to achive data migration is to use so ETL tools.This helps:

1. Fast data migration
2. Accurate data migration
3. Reusable jobs in future
4. Scheduling etc

For MySql I prefer using [Talend Open Studio ETL](http://www.talend.com/products/open-studio-di.php) tool which is open source and you can download it free.

Or you can also use SQL server SSIS.